# New computer getting horrible internet speeds

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

I recently bought a Dell 15 5000, But there is something wrong with the Wi-Fi, all the other devices on my network get speeds of 20+ Mbps, but this computer (just this one) gets horrible speeds of about 2 Mbps... This is only on wireless, ethernet is fine (and this isn't a question of range either, I get the same speed when I stand directly next to the router).

I contacted Microsoft support and looked around the web for some help, but I couldn't find anything that fixed my issue. The Wi-Fi card that I have in the Dell is a Qualcomm QCA9377. When I googled this card specifically,  There were forum posts about people who had the same issue with their computers.

I tried updating the drivers, disabled it, enabled it, but it still doesn't do anything. So what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you using Win10?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Yes

Comment: Try turning Bluetooth off if you haven't already. Inbuilt Bluetooth hardware can sometime interfere with WiFi connections. If you find your router IP address, running `ping routerIPhere -t` is a quick way to test WiFi reliability (if you're seeing an unreliable ping time there is a problem with the connection).

Comment: What is the router model number and manufacturer you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall SmartByte. When I did this, my speed went to 225, as opposed to 5-15 when SmartByte was installed.

Comment: Strange posting sequence.  The OP posted this as an answer and that was downvoted.  Eight months later, this answer repeats the same solution and it is upvoted and accepted by the OP.

Answer (score -1):

I contacted Dell and they told me what the problem was, the SmartByte app comes preinstalled on Dell devices and it's supposed to speed up your internet, but in some cases, it slows it down, just uninstall it and your wifi speeds up.